# View file content of a file selected by a java script file uploader

Tags: javascript, jquery

In jQuery, I used file input type to upload a file. But now I want to show the content of that uploaded file on the browser without having any communication with the server side.

Is this possible and if so how to that.

Comment: What is the file type/extension ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try [`HTML5 File API`](http://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/):

> Using the File API added to the DOM in HTML5, it's now possible for web content to ask the user to select local files, then read the contents of those files.

Answer (score 0):

HTML5 File API is the answer to what to need. Here is a complete working example of what you want:

http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/